Error 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context even though checked namespaces rebuild etc?
I am getting this error that cant seem to go away on a new screen:

Error CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the
current context

Ive double tripled checked the namespaces. Ive tried deleting the bin and obj folders and doing clean and rebuild. Ive tried changing namespace from ; to } and vice versa. Ive even tried changing the class name just in case. What am I missing?
xaml.cs:
using MyApp.ViewModels.VisitHistory;
namespace MyApp.Views.VisitHistory;
public partial class VisitHistoryDetailsPage : ContentPage
{
    VisitHistoryDetailsPageViewModel VM;

    public VisitHistoryDetailsPage ()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent(); //erroring out for some reason
            this.BindingContext = VM = new VisitHistoryDetailsPageViewModel(this.Navigation);
        }           
    }
}

.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="VisitHistoryDetailsPage"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.VisitHistory.VisitHistoryDetailsPage">
</ContentPage>

ViewModel.cs:
namespace MyApp.ViewModels.VisitHistory
{
public class VisitHistoryDetailsPageViewModel :BaseViewModel
{
    public VisitHistoryDetailsPageViewModel(INavigation nav


can you share the entire solution to check the namespaces. Also wrapping the Initalize with try is "unconventional"

You can check this link about New .Net MAUI App project throws 'The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context' build errors. There are many answers about the related issue.
